# bootstrap-5.0 accordion сохранения состояния при обновлении

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

имеется аккардион c бутстрапп документации:

> https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/5.0/components/accordion/

**Задача:**
необходимо сохранить его состояние `accordion-collapse` при обновлении страницы. то есть если я открыл первый
элемент, то при обновлении этот элемент остается открытым. если второй, то второй тоже и т.д

я нашел похожее решение с `panel-cllapse`, вот оно:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571852/bootstrap-accordion-closes-on-buttonclick-inside-updatepanel

не могу применить его для accordion

accordion, который я применяю: `accordion accordion-flush`

Comment: а) хранить состояние (куки), и генерить на бэкенде в нужном виде б) хранить состояние на клиенте (local/sessionStorage) и переключать на фронте при загрузке в) самый простой вариант - если разметка генерится на клиенте, то просто брать состояние из storage